# Сдетектить переключение вкладки

Tags: javascript, javascript-events

Необходимо в приложении отключать звук, если вкладка неактивна. Не получается найти кроссбраузерный способ.

Пробовал использовать события `onfocus` и `onblur`:

```
window.addEventListener('focus', (e) => this.audioPlayer.onFocus(), false);
window.addEventListener('blur', (e) => this.audioPlayer.onBlur(), false);
```

На ПК это исправно работает, но на Android/IOS не работает вообще. 
Что посоветуете?

Answer (score 1):

Мне удалось найти ответ у наших англоязычных коллег - [Is there a way to detect if a browser window is not currently active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active) ( автор ответа [@DanielBuckmaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/945863/daniel-buckmaster) )

Это функция, которая определяет какие именно события поддерживаются браузером (с какими вендорными префиксами) и вызывает `callback` при изменении `visibility`.

```
module.exports = (callback) => {
  let visible = true;

  if (!callback) {
    throw new Error('onVisibilityChange no callback given');
  }

  function focused() {
    if (!visible) {
      callback(visible = true);
    }
  }

  function unfocused() {
    if (visible) {
      callback(visible = false);
    }
  }

  // Standards:
  if ('hidden' in document) {
    document.addEventListener('visibilitychange',
        function() {(document.hidden ? unfocused : focused)()});
  } else if ('mozHidden' in document) {
    document.addEventListener('mozvisibilitychange',
        function() {(document.mozHidden ? unfocused : focused)()});
  } else if ('webkitHidden' in document) {
    document.addEventListener('webkitvisibilitychange',
        function() {(document.webkitHidden ? unfocused : focused)()});
  } else if ('msHidden' in document) {
    document.addEventListener('msvisibilitychange',
        function() {(document.msHidden ? unfocused : focused)()});
  } else if ('onfocusin' in document) {
    // IE 9 and lower:
    document.onfocusin = focused;
    document.onfocusout = unfocused;
  } else {
    // All others:
    window.onpageshow = window.onfocus = focused;
    window.onpagehide = window.onblur = unfocused;
  }
};
```

Вызывается так:

```
const onVisibilityChange = require('./Helpers/onVisibilityChange');

onVisibilityChange((isVisible) => {
    if(isVisible){
        // Приложение в фокусе
    } else {
        // Приложение НЕ в фокусе
    }
});
```

Данное решение я лично протестил на:

- ПК: Firefox/Chrome
- Android 9: Firefox/Chrome
- IOS 11: Chrome/Safari